# How can I dynamically create ttk widgets depending on the value entered in a ttk.entry box?

Tags: python, python-2.7, tkinter

I am trying to make a GUI where as soon as the user inputs an integer into a `ttk.entry` field, that many checkbuttons need to appear below it. For example, if they put "5" into the entry widget, 5 check buttons need to appear below the entry field.

Edit:

What I ended up using:

```
self.number_of_stages = tk.IntVar()
self.check_box_dict={}
self.num_of_stages={}
self.stagetempvar={}
self.equipment_widgets={}


def centrifugal_compressor_widgets(self):
    self.equipment_widgets.clear()
    self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesLabelCentComp"]=tk.Label(self.parent, text="Number of Stages:", bg="white")
    self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesLabelCentComp"].place(relx=0.5, y=260, anchor="center")

    self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesEntryCentComp"]=ttk.Entry(self.parent, textvariable=self.number_of_stages)
    self.equipment_widgets["NumOfStagesEntryCentComp"].place(relx=0.5, y=290, anchor="center")

def OnTraceCentComp(self, varname, elementname, mode):
    for key in self.check_box_dict:
        self.check_box_dict[key].destroy()
    try:
        if self.number_of_stages.get() <=15 :
            i=1
            self.stagetempvar.clear()
            while i <= self.number_of_stages.get():
                self.stagetempvar[i]=tk.StringVar()
                self.stagetempvar[i].set("Closed")
                self.check_box_dict[i]=ttk.Checkbutton(self.parent, text=i, offvalue="Closed", onvalue="Open",variable=self.stagetempvar[i])
                self.check_box_dict[i].place(relx=(i*(1/(self.number_of_stages.get()+1))), y=360, anchor="center")
                i+=1
    except:
        pass
```

Comment: What part of the problem are you struggling with? Do you know how to do loops in python? Do you know how to call functions from buttons?

Comment: I finally figured it out in the end. I used a `trace()` method on the `IntVar()` referenced in the `ttk` entry field. The trace callback method then destroys the dictionary of checkbox objects (if there were some already existing), and then does some entry validation, and then does a while loop.

Comment: you should have put the requirement that it happens immediately in your question. It would likely have saved some people some time.

Comment: I said "as soon as the user inputs" but I should've been more specific. I thought it would be a simple solution that I was overlooking.

Comment: I think the problem is that the way it's worded, it looked like the question was "how do I create widgets in a loop", when the real problem was "how do I call a function as each character is typed".

Comment: Ill remember that next time I post. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

take a look at the below and let me know what you think...

A very ugly, super basic example:

```
from Tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.geometry('200x200')
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight = 1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight = 1)

win1 = Frame(root, bg= 'blue')
win1.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky='news')


number = IntVar()
entry = Entry(win1, textvariable = number)
entry.pack()
confirm = Button(win1, text = 'Press to create widgets...', command = lambda:create_widgets(number.get()))
confirm.pack()

def create_widgets(number):
    for n in range(0,number):
        Checkbutton(win1, text = 'Checkbutton number : %s' % n).pack()

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. Unfortunately I needed them to be created dynamically as the entry field was typed into, without having to press a button. I ended up using a `trace()` method on the tk entry variable.